# How many files do I have?

Tags: nautilus, files, locate, tree

If I as root in Nautilus at the top directory open the properties I get:

```
Name: /

Type: Folder (inode/directory)

Contents: 1 560 503 items, totalling 414,8 GB
```

Trying `root@nilx:/# locate * | wc` I get

```
2997356 3450407 217324980
```

and `root@nilx:/# tree -ia` gives me

277432 directories, 3293850 files

(directories+files=277432+3293850=3571282)

So how many files do I have?

Answer (score 1):

`locate` is not suitable to count files!

It relies on what is saved in the `updatedb` database. But it leaves out some directories from the database when scanning.
See `/etc/updatedb.conf`

```
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /var/lib/os-prober /var/lib/ceph /home/.ecryptfs /var/lib/schroot".
```

---

**Nautilus** defaults to not include hidden files in the Contents/Totalling section, you have to explicitly enable "show hidden files". Also it does not decend into other file systems, it does report the same as `tree -ixa /` though.

---

`tree` should work just fine.

But you could also use `find`, which should be faster than `tree`:

```
find / -printf . | wc -c
```